# Rails user configurable migrations through views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reflection, metaprogramming

I'm making a business administration Rails app.

Is there any info available on how I can enable admin users to add a new field to a table? Behind the scenes this would generate and run the migration and I guess some metaprogramming to include the field in the index, show and _form.html.rb views..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run migrations like that, but you can solve the problem.

The answer is here

[403-dynamic-forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms?view=comments)

If you con't have a subscription, get one. Railscasts is gold for any rails developer

Basically you make a table in the database for the fields to a model.

For instance

```
class Product
 has_many :product_fields
end   
class ProductFields 
 belongs_to :product
end
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. And to add a whole table..? I'll check out the Rails cast and then see.

Comment: No prob! You run a migration. Yeah, watch the video it gives you the whole setup.